# RegEx issue for custom barcode value

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to parse the following string and can't get the regex quite right even though it is pretty basic. I think I have the optional grouping syntax wrong. The data can be one of the following:

```
PV{X}
PV{X.X}
PV{X.X.X}
PV{X.X.X.X}
```

using:

```
^PV\{\d+(\.\d+){0, 3}\}$
```

where:

- PV is constant.
- The curly braces will always be present.
- X is a positive integer (one or more digits).
- Multiple X values can exist (minimum 1, maximum 4) separated by a dot.

Comment: For me, seems pretty OK. You are using hard-anchors (^,$) so ensure that there are no whitespaces at the beginning and end of the input string. I mean, whitespaces or nonprintable control characters!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: That's right. There are no whitespaces or hidden characters or CR/LF in the input string.

Comment: Hm.. ok, so please post some real sample input, and also say what/how it does not work. Does the regex not match at all? do the capture groups catch wrong data? Also, try removing the space in the {0,3} group. I dont have compiler at hand, maybe it's that.. They don't mention spaces here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Examples of real data include `PV{1}`, `PV{4.5}`, `PV{2.9.5}`, etc. You were right about the space in {0, 3}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so this Regex will do it for you:

```
PV\{(\d+?(?:\.\d+){0,3})\}
```

And here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/aT9vN7) to prove it.

The differences?

First, you had `{0, 3}` and so it thought that was a literal value to match. You just needed to get rid of that `{space}` in there. Next, the optional groups, that could occur `0 - 3` times, I dropped a `?:` in there so it doesn't actually capture that group. And then finally, I wrapped the actual value inside the `{ }` so that it would group that. You may want to change your groupings some, but this will surely match the entire string for you when appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread it for "wrapped the actual value with `{}`"

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, no worries friend.

Comment: Thank you. The space was indeed a silly mistake and was all that was required to make the pattern legal. I'm a novice regex user and won't pretend to understand groups. I assume they would only come in handy if I wanted to extract sub-parts from the string? If so, that is not needed in my case. Just validation of the text in its entirety.

Comment: @RaheelKhan, yes, that exactly what groups are used for.

Comment: So the stripped pattern `^PV\{(\d+(\.\d+){0,3})\}$` should be the least needed right?

Comment: @RaheelKhan, that pattern still has grouping. A *stripped* pattern, that doesn't capture any groups, would be this: `^PV\{\d+(?:\.\d+){0,3}\}$`.

Comment: I see. Just read up on that after your comment. Thank you for the explanation in your answer. Just out of curiosity, would removal of grouping constructs and the introduction of the explicit non-capture group increase performance? I will, of course, do a test myself. This function would be called hundreds of times a second as values are streamed from hardware.

Comment: @RaheelKhan, no you will not see any measurable performance impact either way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39068/discussion-between-raheel-khan-and-neoistheone)

Comment: IMHO, the stripped (?:) pattern will be slightly faster than the capturing one. Both patterns have the same matching work to do, but the capturing one **may** additionally copy/buffer some parts of the text and build a few structures to hold the results. However, seeing how small amount of data it is, it probably will be neglible.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Thanks. I thought so. The data is too small to impact memory and the performance hit should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

> PV{\d{1,4}(.\d{1,4})*}